# How to make score points based on time

Tags: algorithm, leaderboards, time

So the idea is simple.

a) Players why finish the level faster, should get higher score.
b) The levels (1 to N) where every next becomes more difficult should impact the score.

So it's kind of mix of "time to complete" and "level number".

If would know the *fastest possible time* the user can complete the level, I would do the fallowing:

a) If player completes the level in *fastest time*, it gets max score 100.
b) If it takes, for example, twice as long I divide by 2 and get 50.
c) Then I multiple by the level number assuming that every next level is twice as difficult.

Example: Player completes level N two times slower than fastest time, so: Score = 100/2 * N = 50N

But the problem is that I can't really figure out the this *fastest time* for each level, because my game is a complex randomized 4d maze and I have no idea how fast a pro gamer can complete it to define the max score. And without that I have no idea how to calculate the score.

This question is all about: "Can we figure out the score without knowing the *fastest time*"

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like calculating the score is not the hard part you need help with. Could we reframe your question as "how to determine the fastest time to solve a 4D maze"? You'd need to include details of how your maze navigation mechanics work. eg. Does the player accelerate and decelerate, or snap between cells/nodes? That will help us estimate the time needed to execute the fastest possible path.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think we can answer this question without knowing more about the mechanics of your game.

Comment: @DMGregory this topic is all about the question: 'can we figure out the score without knowing the fastest path/time'. If its not possible, it's also an an answer.

Comment: It's a procedural randomized maze. My input is only the seed and the dimensions what kind of dictates the difficulty. The 4 dimension is because it changes in time (also randomly). So it's kind of impossible to calculate the 'fastest' path. That's why I'm looking for alternate ways to defining the score.

Comment: However the answer given from @walkingBird I think will do the trick. Feel free to add other solutions, if can think of any!

Comment: I don't think you should conclude it's impossible so readily. If you walk us through the generation and modification algorithm, we may be able to compute that fastest time for you. Or at least a reasonable approximation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define whater max score you want for any level.

then at the end of the run you give play the score = MAX_SCORE_ON_THIS_LEVEL / time_to_complete.

This way the Max score is known, none can get more than "MAX_SCORE_ON_THIS_LEVEL", if the dont complete it in less than one second ofc

Comment: So if i set it to 100 and player solves it in 2 hours (7200 seconds) the score would be 0.014. If in half hour its 0.05. This could work, but numbers are bit of ugly. What is probably better than trying to figure out the optimal time.

Comment: Just scale it after,  Into a Range you like. Maybe some flooring of the values also, to get some Nice integers